# Changing the text color of an element is not working

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to change the text color of a div with the class `.highlight` in the code below, but it isn't working.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
.highlight {
  font-color: #FF3300;
  font-style: oblique;
  line-height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="highlight">
  <h4>ASSOCIATED PRESS</h4>
</div>
<br>
<h3 style="line-height:100%">4.6/5</h3>
<div class="highlight">
  <h4>GOODREADS</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Trying to make the text oblique and orange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change css to

```
.highlight h4 {
color: #FF3300;
font-style: oblique;
line-height: 20%;
}
```

Comment: font-color is not a css style you should use color

Comment: How did you come up with such an answer. The question is not clear!

Answer (score 1):

Change your `CSS`

```
.highlight {
color: #FF3300;
font-style: oblique;
line-height: 20%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5mr2wLgy/

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to change the text color because `font-color` is not a valid CSS property. To set the foreground color of an element's text content, use the [`color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color) CSS property.

```css
.highlight {
  color: #FF3300;
  font-style: oblique;
  line-height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="highlight">
  <h4>ASSOCIATED PRESS</h4>
</div>
<br>
<h3 style="line-height:100%">4.6/5</h3>
<div class="highlight">
  <h4>GOODREADS</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Either add

```
h4 {
  color: #FF3300;
  font-style: oblique;
  line-height: 20%;
}
```

or

```
.highlight h4 {
  color: #FF3300;
  font-style: oblique;
  line-height: 20%;
}
```